# Python Selenium And BS

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Ive Been Trying to get an element from a page that Ive clicked on to get into the next page with soup.find_all.
The problem is that it gives me the elements of the first page.
Thanks in Advance.

The code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Graph/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://blockchain.coinmarketcap.com/chain/bitcoin")
time.sleep(2)


next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_page_css)))

time.sleep(0.1)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(next_page).perform()

next_page.click()
time.sleep(0.1)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

stats = str(soup.find_all('tbody', {"class": "ant-table-tbody"}))
print(stats)
driver.quit()
```

The Website: https://blockchain.coinmarketcap.com/chain/bitcoin

[Photo Of The Button Im Clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okPma.png)

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It's impossible to read. *Edit* your question to include the extra code. Link bottom left, next to Share.

Comment: Oh Sorry! Im quite new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not too sure what you wanted to get from it, I managed to took the data from page2.

seem to have 2 problem from what i can see:
1)The sleep time was not enough for the page to load
2)Had to change the CSS selector as was not working

```
next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ant-pagination-item-2")))

time.sleep(2)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(next_page).perform()

next_page.click()
time.sleep(2)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

stats = str(soup.find_all('tbody', {"class": "ant-table-tbody"}))
print(stats)
```

Returned :

```
<tbody class="ant-table-tbody"><tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0" data-row-key="0000000000000000000aae7c345c1b0acde7650e5448ca5dfc6c8de7d415ed22">
```

Comment: It Worked! Thank you so much.
that didnt print what u showed but it printed what ive wanted so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the delay after clicking the `next_page.click()` before `content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()` to make the page load a next page data.
It's not recommended to use hardcoded sleep.
Some better way to do it would to get data presented on the previous page and then use some kind of expected conditions to wait until the previous data no more presented.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,element_located_by_previous_value)))
```

Comment: Tried to do it like that and still did not work:

    content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    stats = str(soup.find_all('tbody', {"class": "ant-table-tbody"}))
    next_page.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, stats)))
    content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    stats = str(soup.find_all('tbody', {"class": "ant-table-tbody"}))

Comment: I don't really understand this comment, sorry. Did you increase the sleep time after `next_page.click()`? Put 2-3 seconds sleep there. At it still doesn't work?

Comment: yes, that did not work.
Ive also tried taking the element from the first page and then using the code line u suggessed.
like so:

stats = str(soup.find_all('tbody', {"class": "ant-table-tbody"}))

......

 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, stats)))

Comment: Well, if so I currently have no more ideas, busy with my work, sorry

Comment: Well Thanks Anyway!